# How can Newbies Help

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users, etiquette

I realize I must earn privileges to participate, but how can I approach the situation below calmly and formulate the full answer when I get this type of response:

A Recent post from SuperUser.  See [original post](https://superuser.com/questions/742729/make-error-as-unable-to-find-cblas).

> I don't have 50 rep yet so I can't add a comment, but it looks as if you may need 1 more library. Does this link help?

To which I received a comment:

> I'll convert this to a comment, but this is an exception.. please answer questions where you don't need additional info first, until you have 50 reputation. Then you're free to comment everywhere. Thanks –  slhck♦ 2 hours ago

While that may be the rule that rather rude response makes me want to stay away from that exchange portal, which is the opposite approach I want to take.  What is the correct method for new users to help with questions when a new user hasn't earned all the tools?

Comment: You should provide *answers*, rather than posting non-answers as answers.  More than anything else, you should be here to either ask or answers questions.  The fact that you can't do much else at 1 rep is to drill that into your head.  Asking and answering is more important than anything else.  All of your activities should center around doing that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does a new user begin using Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188611/how-does-a-new-user-begin-using-stack-overflow-stack-exchange). See also [How does a lurker gain reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164035/how-does-a-lurker-gain-reputation)

Comment: Sorry you found slhck's response rude, but that means you must be quite easily offended; I see it as *helpful* comment! The moderator could easily just have deleted your answer without comment, but instead he took out time to direct you to the proper way to participate instead.

Comment: @Everyone... It's not that I don't get or understand all these comments, it's more how do i nudge a poster in the right direction if all my nudges need to be comments when I can't comment?

Comment: Have a look at my 1 step program @ECarterYoung. It's available to all at 12 easy monthly payments of 0 Unicoins.

Comment: @ECarterYoung You *don't*.  You post some quality questions or answers until you get to 50 rep and have the ability to comment.  Until then you just don't comment, rather than trying to post comments when you don't have the permission for it.

Comment: To be blunt (and I guess you'll find this rude too, but...) if you think that moderator message is _rude_, you're not going to like it here.

Comment: @JoshCaswell... Comments like this are fine.  That's not what got to me.  Surely the moderator can see my reputation, and that I'm below the 50 point req, but yet he still says it should be a comment.  I'll just stick to Servy's advice

Comment: How does your reputation have anything to do with whether your answer should have been a comment or not? The fact that you (currently) can't post comments does not mean you should feel free to post them as answers instead.

Comment: Oh, I see, you find the _action_ rude, not the comment. I can understand why you think _that_, though I believe you're mistaken.

Comment: That's the point though.  I did not know the proper etiquette was to ignore the question until I had rep as  Servy pointed out

Comment: @ECarter it is an odd rule, sadly it has proven neccisary (comments aren't as aggressively moderated as answers)

Comment: Then I dont mind it, and now you won't hear me complaining

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140988/ways-to-make-impact-on-a-site-in-which-you-have-little-knowledge-of-the-topic

Answer (score 5):

> What is the correct method for new users to help with questions when a new user hasn't earned all the tools?

Step 1: earn the tools.

Really, that is all there is to it. And you can do so by contributing actual questions, great answers, and by suggesting edits if that is something you like and you're good at.

The comment is actually quite nice. In the majority of cases "answers" like that are just outright nuked. So for the moderator to take this route for you is something he should be thanked for.

You might find all of this a bit strange, perhaps unwelcoming even, but it helps us to keep sites clean and the quality of content high. A bit of a hurdle, sure, but one you can most certainly overcome with a bit of work.

So put in a bit of effort and you'll be good to go in no time. Good luck. ;)

Comment: If he earned the tools then he technically is not a newbie anymore. So, basically you are not answering the question.

Comment: @Mhmd If you have other options for the OP to help out besides the ones I mentioned, somehow overcoming the initial hurdles put in front of him, by all means contribute your own answer. Surprise me.

Comment: @Mhmd so editing a few posts and asking a question would make OP a well versed SO user? The edit entry barrier is very low as it is...